# Sorting a matrix by a list in R

Tags: r

I want to sort a matrix based a list using R. However, for each element in that list, there are multiple rows correlate to single element in the list. Example is shown below:

```
Name    value 
 A        1
 B        2
 B        4
 C        5

l <- c("C", "B", "A")
```

if I want to change the matrix to

```
Name    value 
 C        5
 B        2
 B        4
 A        1
```

What should I do?

Comment: I just changed your `list <- c(C, B, A)` to `l <- c("C", "B", "A")`, edit the question if this is not what you intended. BTW `list` is not a good name for a vector as it is an internal function in R so changed it to `l` instead.

Comment: Do you have a matrix or a dataframe? a list or a vector? You want to also sort by `value` within each group? Please provide a reproducible example and be more specific as there is no such thing as `list <- c(C, B, A)` and a matrix can't hold multiple column types (like you showed). You can use `dput` on your objects and post here so we could reproduce.

Comment: `df[order(match(df$Name,l)),]`  from the duplicated post.

Comment: Sorry about the inaccurate information. I think I have a dataframe and a vector. The value within each group does not really matter. Please let me know if additional information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
DT <- fread(
"Name    value 
A        1
B        2
B        4
C        5")
l <- c("C", "B", "A")
DT[l, on="Name"]
# > DT[l, on="Name"]
#    Name value
# 1:    C     5
# 2:    B     2
# 3:    B     4
# 4:    A     1
```

`data.table` conserves the order of the rows during operations.
Here is a variant with base `R`:

```
df <- as.data.frame(DT)
merge(data.frame(Name=l), df, sort=FALSE)
```